# Adobe AIR. Open app from tray with double click

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I've used example from [here](http://www.swamicharan.com/blog/air/minimizing-an-air-app-to-systemtray/comment-page-1/)

App doesn't open with double click.

Works

```
SystemTrayIcon(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, unDock);
```

Doesn't work

```
SystemTrayIcon(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon).addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, unDock);
```

Comment: seem like someone has reported this on an Adobe forum and didn't get much in terms of answers: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/100056

Comment: Thank you. Please post it as answer and I'll mark it as correct answer

Comment: Technically, it is not a bug, because SystemTrayIcon has click event, but not doubleClick: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/SystemTrayIcon.html#methodSummary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alxx mentioned, this is not a bug, just a limitation.

What you should do is just listen for the click event and compare a the timestamp (getTimer()) between the 2 clicks, if under 400ms, then undock.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks J_A_X. :)

```
        SystemTrayIcon(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openWindow);

        private var previousTimeStamp:int;

        private function openWindow(event:Event):void
        {
            var currentTimeStamp:int = getTimer();

            if(currentTimeStamp)
            {
                if(currentTimeStamp - previousTimeStamp < 400)
                {
                    // double click
                    trace("double click");
                }
            }
            previousTimeStamp = getTimer();
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.